# .NET 301 redirect rule issue - might conflict with other rules

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, web-config

I already have a "http to https" rule and a "remove www" rule up and running.
See code end of question.
I now want to add another rule that matches "øwebsite.com" and redirects to "website.com". Notice the special character "ø". No idea if that's important or not.

Looking at my two other working rules I figured this was how to do it:

```
<rule name="øwebsite to website" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^øwebsite\.com$" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^øwebsite\.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://website.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
```

I have the above chunck placed in between these two other rules with config transformations elsewhere for attributes "enabled":

```
        <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="false" enabled="false">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions >
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^get$|^head$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="staging" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="development" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://website.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
```

```
<rule name="Removewww" stopProcessing="false" enabled="false">
      <match url="(.*)" negate="false"></match>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://website.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

**Should I combine my new rule with one of the two or have I simply done something wrong in my new rule?**